# Error: syntax error, unexpected identifier, expecting "," or )

Tags: scilab

Soy nueva programando en este lenguaje por lo tanto no conozco bien la sintaxis, a partir de la línea 13 `printf(’\n The horizontal force at C...`.me sale el error

> Error: syntax error, unexpected identifier, expecting "," or )

```
clear all; clc ;
disp("1.1 :")
w_varying=270;
l_crossection=9;
l_cb=6;
l_ac =2;
w_c =( w_varying/l_crossection ) * l_cb 
f_resultant_c = 0.5*w_c*l_cb
n_c = 0
v_c = f_resultant_c
m_c = -(f_resultant_c*l_ac)

printf(’\n The horizontal force at C=%.2f N’,C=%.2fN’,f_resultant_c);
printf(’\nThe vertical force at C = %. 2 f N ’,v_c );
printf(’\nThe moment about C= %.2fNm’ , m_c );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo que en la esa línea tienes una comilla de más

```
printf(’\n The horizontal force at C=%.2f N’,C=%.2fN’,f_resultant_c);
```

podrías intentar quitandola y quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
printf(’\n The horizontal force at C=%.2f N’,C=%.2fN,f_resultant_c);
```

puede que sea el error.